# Asynchronous property of JavaScript causing error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous, fetch

I am facing an issue while creating the register page of my application. I have a react front end and a node/express back end. I need to perform the following in react -

1. Make a backend call to node and check if user exists
2. if user does not exist, make a backend call to node and add user to database.

But due to asynchronous property of JavaScript, before the response of step 1 is received, step 2 is executed. This is causing duplicate entries in the MongoDB table. I have tried using the .then() function and yet could not resolve. Is it maybe because I used .then() in a wrong way? How do I resolve this issue?

I am very new to asynchronous programming and this can very well be a rookie mistake. But kindly enlighten me.

I also cannot share the code since it is proprietary, hope you can understand.

**UPDATE:**
I could code a similar scenario. Kindly take a look below -

```
const addUser = (name, email, password, confirm, error, setError) => {
    setError('')
    if (name.length <= 0) {
        setError('Name can not be blank')
    }
    if (email.length <= 0) {
        setError('Email cannot be blank')
    }
    if (!email.includes("@")) {
        setError('Invalid email')
    }
    if (password.length <= 0) {
        setError('Password can not be blank')
    }
    if (password !== confirm) {
        setError('Passwords do not match')
    }

    fetch(`${host}check_user_exists`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email: email})
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            console.log('response')
            return response.json()
        }
    ).then(
        function (result) {
            console.log('error')
            if(result.user === 'duplicate') {
                setError('User already exists')
                console.log(error)
                return error
            }
        }
    ).then(
        function (error) {
            console.log('add')
            if (error !== 'User already exists'){
                fetch(`${host}add_user`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    ).catch( 
        err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code as text in your question.

Comment: If you cannot share the code due to proprietary reasons, then create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi guys, I have added the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a middleware in the registration route to check if the user/email already exists and not having to make two different requests. But if you need them anyway because you want to do a validation in real time you could try something like this:

```html
const checkUser = async (username) => {
  await axios 
    .post(API_URL + "/auth/signUpCheck", {
      username: username,
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
      //response from API with value of check
      if (response) {
        return await "other axios post for add user";
      } else {
        //already exists
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
};
```

Or use middleware in the registration route (backend):

```html
checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = (req, res, next) => {
  // Username
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      username: req.body.username
    }
  }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      res.status(400).send({
        message: "User already exists !"
      });
      return;
    }

    // Email
    User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: req.body.email
      }
    }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        res.status(400).send({
          message: "Email already exists!"
        });
        return;
      }

      next();
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried out the solutions you mentioned, it is still not working. I have added code snippet to the issue. Kindly check and see if you can help